# WPF ensure transformed content is visible

Tags: wpf, transformation, bounding-box

Does WPF provide a control that automatically transforms contained content to be visible?

I can compute things manually, but I'd rather work with existing Dependency Properties.

I'd like to add content to this hypothetical control, rotate the content, and have the parent perform additional transformation to make sure the entire content is visible.

(Similar to [Smallest possible bounding box for a rotated image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567644/smallest-possible-bounding-box-for-a-rotated-image))

Comment: What kind of additional transformation do you expect the parent to do?  There are options like ViewBox behavior, scrolling, etc.  If you build up your control in terms of existing controls then calling EnsureVisible() on the child should do the right thing.

Comment: What you describe is typically done by a [LayoutTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.layouttransform.aspx), which could be used instead of a [RenderTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransform.aspx).

Comment: This parent control has a fixed size.  When I add content to it, the content may require a scale to be completely enclosed by the parent.  I can do the math, but I don't want to unless I must.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the whole content into a [Viewbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms617883).